# No DNS - I just lost all edit info in wikipedia when submitting, is there anything I can do?

Tags: google-chrome, http, request, submit, wikipedia

I'm in chrome. I submitted a long edit that I worked on extensively.
I got: The site cannot be reached. I hit enter on the chrome address bar with
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Talk:Somepage&action=submit
and got the old page without my edit.

Help!!!  Is there anything I can do to retrieve the intended submittal text?

------- edited -----------
When I hit the BACK button on Chrome. It asked me if I wanted to leave the session.
When I said yes it gave me the website I was on before entering WP.
Hitting FORWARD brought me back to the same page open for edit without my text!

OK. I duplicated the page, and hit the back button, this time (don't ask me why) when hitting BACK, and after accepting the "leave this page?", it gave me my text!!!  Yay!!!!

So now: Anybody? Care to explain why and how this happened and what to do exactly, next time this happens to anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the page, and hit the back button, this time (don't ask me why) when hitting BACK, and after accepting the "leave this page?", it will give your text back. Yay!!!!